# C# console application

Tags: c#, console

I have sample exe say console.exe on "programfiles\myAppFolder" .It serves the purpose of logging the message to eventviewer

```
EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent, EventLogEntryType.Warning,  234);
```

I need to call this exe on un-install of appcn from NSIS script .However it gives me an error always that "thisappConsole has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience."

Even browsing to the path "programfiles\myAppFolder\thisappConsole.exe" and manually clicking on it to execute even throws the same error. I do have admin access to m/c.

Can anyone help me with this.

If I put any other simple console app without any additional "using statements". it works fine ..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your event log application is throwing an unhandled exception, quite ironic considering it is an application for logging events!

I would put my money on it being a permissions issue as the event log needs to access the registry. As a work-around try running your application as an Admin. Would be handy to handle the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event and log the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Press F5.

This will run the programme in the debugger, and you the unhandled exception will be displayed on screen.  It will give a exception type, message, and line number.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
Try
{
  your app code here
}
Catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Logg ex.ToString()
}
```

Comment: its failing to initialize..the exeception is not throwing inside the application..

Comment: @Andy it still sounds like an unhandled exception in some code that's running whenever your app starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try
{
  your  code here
}
Catch (Exception ex)
{
  ex.message="";
}
finally 
{}

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure you have the same version of the .Net framework installed on that machine, and also any referenced .dll's are in the same folder as the .exe.